# Excel Formula with same folder path

Tags: excel-formula

I have a folder in desktop Project-1. there is 2 file in that folder. one is GL another is 001.  i used a formula in 001 to sum from GL excel file the formula is
=SUM('C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Project-1[GL.xls]GL'!$F$1:$F$200,)

I want to use the formula without file path like =sum(\[GL.xls]GL'!$F$1:$F$200)

How can i do that?

Comment: Then the file will need to be open.

Comment: Your intent is to hide the path.. Or to have a formula that will work wherever the (both) file is moved?